# Java: Embed heavyweight components in lightweight (JavaFX SwingNode)

Tags: java, applet, javafx, embed

I have been developing a JavaFX application which I need to embed a [Applet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html) into. This question has [already been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23662895/is-it-possible-to-use-an-existing-applet-within-a-javafx-application-desktop/23666061#23666061); however the answer given on that question is not sufficient. I do not have access to the applet, I am simply downloading it off a server (game server in this case) and trying to run it on the desktop as my own custom client. So I cannot change anything on that side. I can easily do this using swing alone, but not when embedding into a SwingNode on a JavaFX application. I have spent days reading up about it and I understand the problems with not being able to put heavyweight components into a SwingNode and rely on having them work. However with anything when there's a will there is always a way.

The code I am current using:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    primaryStage.setTitle("GameClient");

    //Game launcher
    Launcher launcher = new Launcher();

    SwingNode swingNode = new SwingNode();
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> swingNode.setContent(launcher.getGameClientWrappedInJPanel()));

    //HBox because I also want to add another component off to the side of the game
    Scene scene = new Scene(new HBox());
    ((HBox)scene.getRoot()).getChildren().add(swingNode);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.sizeToScene();
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

Also, all advice is welcomed but keep in mind that this is all a testing set up; so things like the launcher downloading and initializing the client in the constructor is just a temporary work around.

So long story short, I was wondering if anyone would be able to give me any advice on how to handle this. (Basically a hack for properly rendering heavyweight in lighweight components) I have considered writing the overall gui in Swing and just using JFXPanels for the FX components, but if there is any hack I could use for my original goal; it would be a lot more convenient.

Thank you

*-Thomas*