# Java - How can I implement an Applet into a JavaFX component?

Tags: java, javafx, applet, jtabbedpane

I would like some advice on which GUI framework to use. Currently I have my application working in Swing. It includes an AppletStub running in a JTabbedPane tab.

I am thinking of switching the GUI over to JavaFX but I cannot find the equivalent way of achieving what I already have (see above).

Comment: Maybe additional possiblities exist, but you can achieve it like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37284366/javafx-tab-pane-with-multiple-rows/37321875#37321875

JavaFX has a really good CSS styling system, so you can customize it as you want.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but my main issue is whether or not I can display an applet inside JavaFX components.

Comment: Ah, I totally missed that part, sorry. 

To answer that, JavaFX has a SwingNode, where you can embed you existing Applet. Please see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23662895/is-it-possible-to-use-an-existing-applet-within-a-javafx-application-desktop. However it is for `javax.swing.JApplet`.
You could try this, or if your Applet is not too huge, consider to reimplement it.

Comment: Done, thanks for the advice